# Align text to the icon

Tags: html, css

Please assist me aligning the icon and text vertically

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="opretForum">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="/opret-forum/">Opret Forum</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#opretForum li {
    list-style-image: url('/img/forum/tilfoj.png');
}

#opretForum ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, what is the problem?

Comment: The green icon is not vertically aligned with the text

Comment: Please create an example on a site like jsfiddle so we can see the test case and play around, thanks!

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, that's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it ain't possible to align the list-style-image. The method that is often used is as follow:

http://jsfiddle.net/fcPNp/

```
li {
  background: url('/img/forum/tilfoj.png') no-repeat left center;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: #opretForum { background-color:black; padding:5px; width:200px; }
#opretForum a { text-decoration:none; color:white} http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/uLwtr/

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
<style>
#opretForum li { list-style:none; background:url('/img/forum/tilfoj.png');vertical-align:middle }
</style>

<div id="opretForum">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="/opret-forum/">Opret Forum</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```